# CSV file to MySQL, "Error No: 0"

Tags: php, mysql, csv

So I'm trying to create a MySQL table from a CSV file using this script:
https://github.com/uzi88/PHP_MySQL_wrapper#create-table-from-csv-file

The script I'm using is a slight modification to the one in the link.
The only difference is that the script I'm using is made to loop through a list.
Here's the modified part:

```
$filename = 'csv_list.txt';
$contents = file($filename);


/* Loops through list of CSV-files and create a table for each CSV-file */
foreach($contents as $line) {

    /* Cuts off file extension */
    $file_info = pathinfo($line);
    $file_name = $file_info['filename'];

    $db->dropTable($file_name);
    $db->createTableFromCSV('/csv/'.$file_name.'.csv', $file_name);

    }
```

But I get the error `"ERROR -> NO -> 0 - DESC ->  - CALL -> Function createTableFromCSV in csv_to_mysql.php on line 32"`. 
I can't seem to find any information about this error.

Here are a few rows from the CSV file I'm trying to import.

```
Disease,County,Year,Sex,Count,Population,Rate,CI.lower,CI.upper,Unstable
Amebiasis,California,2001,Total,571,34514777,1.654,1.521,1.796, 
Amebiasis,California,2001,Female,176,17340743,1.015,0.871,1.176, 
Amebiasis,California,2001,Male,365,17174034,2.125,1.913,2.355, 
Amebiasis,El Dorado,2006,Total,0,175258,0,0,2.105,-
Amebiasis,El Dorado,2006,Female,0,87654,0,0,4.208,-
Amebiasis,El Dorado,2006,Male,0,87604,0,0,4.211,-
Amebiasis,El Dorado,2007,Total,1,177195,0.564,0.014,3.144,*
Amebiasis,El Dorado,2007,Female,1,88622,1.128,0.029,6.287,*
```

I've also tried with a new file where I removed the column "Unstable" because some values where empty. I also renamed CI.lower and CI.upper

```
Disease,County,Year,Sex,Count,Population,Rate,CIlower,CIupper
Amebiasis,California,2001,Total,571,34514777,1.654,1.521,1.796
Amebiasis,California,2001,Female,176,17340743,1.015,0.871,1.176
Amebiasis,California,2001,Male,365,17174034,2.125,1.913,2.355
```

Here's a link to the complete CSV file:
https://cdph.data.ca.gov/api/views/yijp-bauh/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Is that really the exact error message you get?

Comment: @Barmar
Yes, this is the exact error message I get.

Comment: @Barmar

The code is a slight modification of the one you find in the Git project I linked to.
The only difference is that this script is modified to loop through a list of CSV files.

`
$filename = 'csv_list.txt';
$contents = file($filename);


/* Loops through list of CSV-files and create a table for each CSV-file */
foreach($contents as $line) {

 /* Cuts off file extension */
 $file_info = pathinfo($line);
 $file_name = $file_info['filename'];
 
 $db->dropTable($file_name);
 $db->createTableFromCSV('/csv/'.$file_name.'.csv', $file_name);

 } `

It works fine with most other CSV files.

Comment: That's unreadable. Edit the question so you can post the code with readable formatting.

Comment: You've been a SO member for 2 years, you should know the proper way to post a question.

Comment: @Barmar

For some reason it didn't output the code formatting correct even though I put it within ` `

But you find the relevant code in the link in the original post, I also added the code that I've modified.

Comment: Paste your code into the SO editor. Mark it with the mouse. Click on the `{ }` tool or type Control-k to mark it as a code block.

Comment: You say your script is a "slight modification" of the script at the link. We need to see what you've done in your modification, because that's probably where the problem is.

Comment: The reason why I did not add the code I've modified is because the error I'm getting is when I'm calling "createTableFromCSV()", which is a function that I haven't modified.

This function works with other CSV-files, but not with the one I've linked in the post.

Comment: Are you sure the pathname is correct? `'/csv/'.$file_name` means the `csv` directory is in the root directory of your filesystem. Maybe you shouldn't have the first `/`, so it will look in a subdirectory of the current directory.

Comment: Well, that library makes it difficult to tell where the error really happened. When it prints the function call backtrace, it skips any functions that are in the library itself. See line 1368 of `MySQL_wrapper.class.php`.

Comment: @Barmar 
Thanks for taking the time and looking it through.

Do you have any other suggestions how I could create a MySQL table from the CSV file in the link?

Comment: Just use MySQL's built-in `LOAD TABLE INFILE` query.

Comment: @Barmar I've started to look into that. But I do not know how to enclose columns with "" in the CSV file.

Comment: You don't need to enclose columns in quotes unless the column value can contain a comma.